# Testing socket.io with mocha

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, socket.io, mocha.js

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
     // getSessionID is parsing socket.request.headers.cookie for sid
     let sessionID = getSessionID(socket);            
});
```

i'm using socket.request.headers.cookie to get the session id and then mapping that to socket id....

So my problem is when i'm running mocha tests i won't have any session or cookies set. I really don't want to modify my server to cater to the test i.e. passing through a fake session ID as query.

I was thinking of using selenium but would it be overkill is there a simpler approach.

Comment: maybe not the best solution but right now i'm just using supertest to establish a session and passing the session ID through in handshake.query     on the server im just using an env variable to flip between (socket.handshake.session  and socket.handshake.query) for testing and prod. not too happy about how i'm doing it but will revisit it later.